# Reliable way to determine the notation mode (R1C1 or A1) of Excel formulas

Tags: ms-office, office-js

(* I re-ask a question that I post 5 years ago *)

When we develop Excel add-ins by JavaScript API, we need to determine if the user is currently on R1C1 or A1-notation mode to display their formulas.

Is there any JavaScript API to do so?

Otherwise, does anyone have a reliable way to obtain this information?

Comment: Can you use toJSON() on the context.application object to get a list of all the properties?

Comment: I don't see the notation mode in the list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.application?view=excel-js-preview

Comment: Yes, I didn't see it in the docs either, that's why I was wondering what happened if you dumped the object to JSON.   But if it's not, you should be able to tell the reference style from the text of any formula.

Comment: There are 3 APIs to get a formula: `formulas` (A1), `formulasLocal` (A1), `formulasR1C1` (R1C1). They are all independent from the real-time setting of the system.

Comment: What happens if you use a `=Formulatext(A1)` on a cell with a formula? Does that result reflect the notation mode?

Comment: I just tested, what `Formulatext` returns reflects the real-time notation mode of the system.